# Are there any complete tables that can accurately pinpoint the year of the flood?

Tags: genesis, flood-of-noah, chronology

Answers in Genesis -> [Timeline for the Flood](https://answersingenesis.org/bible-timeline/timeline-for-the-flood/) says that the Flood happened in 1656 *Anno Mundi.*

However, they don't provide similar table to tell that the exact same Flood starts at 2348 BC. Instead it just quotes a source.

Anywhere I can find such tables in quick and easy to read format? There should be continuation after that?

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about the date of the [Great Flood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_flood_narrative) within the generational dating of the book of Genesis, there are many tables that show this. Here is one example:

[image]

*(Note: Posting of this table does not imply agreement with all of its text.)*

Though there are similar tables that continue the dating through the rest of the Old Testament to the time of Christ, connecting the Flood to our current calendar system, they are necessarily based on less solid genealogies and dates in the Bible, especially during the five or six centuries from the time of the Babylonian captivity to the time of Christ, in which there are major gaps in the biblical record. At that point the dating depends on extra-biblical historical sources providing possible dates for historical events recorded in the Bible.

Further, though we can date the Babylonian captivity fairly accurately from extra-biblical historical records (Babylonian, Persian, etc.) the biblical dating from the time of the Egyptian captivity to the time of the Babylonian captivity is nowhere near as clear-cut as it is from Adam to Joseph, making it difficult to pin down exactly how many years elapsed during that time period.

All of this is why there is not the level of agreement in biblical dating from the time of Joseph to Christ, and up to the present calendar system, that there is from the time of Adam to Joseph, even if we assume that the Bible provides an accurate and historical account of the events it describes.

Comment: Is the date of babylonian captivity correctly determined?

Comment: @JimThio I don't know how accurate our date on that is. The Bible itself doesn't provide any dating that would accurately connect it with our present dating system. So scholars weigh in with material based on Babylonian records, etc.

Comment: @JimThio If you do a simply Google image search for "Bible Timeline" you will see a number of charts that go up to the birth of Christ. But they don't necessarily agree with one another, and it gets especially fuzzy after the end of the Monarchy. That's because the precise dating is somewhat speculative.

Comment: @JimThio About the Babylonian captivity specifically, see the Wikipedia article on that subject: [Babylonian captivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_captivity).

Comment: The dating of the Babylonian Captivity is particularly well-determined, because we know from Babylonian, Persian and other records when Nebucchadnezzar besieged Jerusalem, and when Cyrus defeated him. It is the previous stretch of the Monarchy and the Judicate, for which there is no extra-Biblical corroboration and the Bible itself is not necessarily scrupulous to count, which cause the variance of dates for earlier events.

Comment: @Wtrmute I've done a major revision of the answer based on the comments, yours especially.

Comment: The Babylonian captivity began  587/586 BC as reported by Wikipedia and Jewish sources. It ended when Cyrus the Great of Persia defeated Babylon around 520 BC and allowed the Jews to return where the began working on the second Temple around 515 BC. Among the conquerors over the centuries, the Greeks took the Temple in the 3rd century BC. The Jews briefly and independently held the Temple beginning in 166 BC with an army led by Judah Maccabee. I don't remember the date the Romans moved in, but this only a comment, so ...

Comment: The Jewish website Chabad.org lists the year of the flood as 2104 BC. It doesn't list any charts.

Comment: This is indeed 1656 from creation, but its possible there is variance from the changing from lunar to solar calendar.